# Rails 4 nested route for managing HABTM relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a `Client` model which has a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship with the `CronJob` model.

Now to give a client the ability to enable/disbale a given list of crons for themselves I want to make a controler separate from the `CronJobsController` in `app/controllers/cron_jobs_controller.rb`. I want it to sit neatly namespaced under the clients folder and simply call it `CronsController` (`app/controllers/clients/crons_controller.rb`). The question is how to set up the routes file so I get these routes available to me:

- `clients` --> `/clients`
- `client_crons` --> `/clients/:client_id/crons`
- `append_client_cron` --> `post` -> `/clients/:client_id/crons/:id`
- `remove_client_cron` --> `delete` -> `/clients/:client_id/crons/:id`

Right now my `routes.rb` has this, which is close but not quite

```
resources :clients do
    namespace :clients do
        resources :crons, only: ['index'] do
          member do
            post :append
            delete :remove
          end
        end
    end
  end
```

which results in:

```
    append_client_clients_cron POST   /clients/:client_id/clients/crons/:id/append(.:format)     clients/crons#append
    remove_client_clients_cron DELETE /clients/:client_id/clients/crons/:id/remove(.:format)     clients/crons#remove
          client_clients_crons GET    /clients/:client_id/clients/crons(.:format)                clients/crons#index
```

The problem here is `/clients/:client_id/clients/crons/` with this extra `clients` in the middle.

I know I could just leave the namespace out of it and would get the desired route but that would make the folder architecture quite unwieldy since there will be a number of these HABTM relationships on various models.

Alternatively is there a way I can tell the routes file to look in the clients subfolder for the crons resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resources :clients do
    scope module: :clients do
      resources :crons, only: ['index'] do
        member do
          post :append
          delete :remove
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks. IDK who downvoted but this works great for me. In addition I changed the `member` block to `post '/', to: 'crons#append'` and now I get post to `/clients/:client_id/crons/:id`